# Is "01/02/2022 + 1 month" saying output is 2/2/2022 a bug in the date command?

Tags: bash, shell, date

on bash (GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)), I am adding a month to a certain date using the following operation (please note the format):

```
date +%d/%m/%Y -d "01/02/2022 + 1 month"
```

It gives 02/02/2022 (wrong it is adding the +1 month to the day).
Then I tried:

```
date +%d/%m/%Y -d "01/02/2022 + 2 month"
```

It gives 02/03/2022 (half wrong, it is adding +1 to the day and +1 to the month).
Instead:

```
date +%d/%m/%Y -d "02/02/2022 + 1 month"
```

gives: 02/03/2022 (correct).

Did I find a bug?

Comment: `date` is not part of bash; it's provided by your operating system. The `date` you have on MacOS is _completely_ different from the one you have on Linux, even with the same version of bash installed on each, so it's critical to specify your OS in questions on the topic, whereas the bash version is irrelevant. (That said, in this particular case, the command you gave wouldn't work with BSD date at all, so it's certain you have GNU date).

Comment: Also relevant for your question's purposes is your locale settings, which determine (among other things) what the default date representation is; in the US, MM-DD-YYYY is common, whereas in Europe, DD-MM-YYYY is common. Of course, using YYYY-MM-DD makes your locale irrelevant altogether.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the locale is not used to interpret the input format. `xx/xx/xxxx` is always interpreted as `mm/dd/yyyy`. `xxxx-xx-xx` is interpreted as `yyyy-mm-dd`. `xx-xx-xxxx` isn't even accepted.

Comment: This is a big reason I prefer the BSD `date` command, which lets you provide a input format as well as an output format.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just saw that "date" is not a built-in command. My OS is Linux Mint 19.3 - "Tricia".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You used a date format that can be interpreted in two ways and `date` (not related to bash) chose the interpretation different to yours:

- January 2nd + 1 month = February 2nd, OK.
- January 2nd + 2 months = March 2nd, OK.

The third date is the same in both the interpretations.

Note that the input format is independent of the output format.

*Conclusion:* Always use `+%Y-%m-%d`. It can be sorted alphabetically and is not interpreted as `+%Y-%d-%m` as no one uses that format.

Comment: Interesting reply, but it is not consistent with all the examples I gave. Also, using your interpretation, the second case, with +2 months, gives February 3rd. Is it?

Comment: No, you asked the output in the `+%d/%m/%Y` format. But it doesn't influence the input format.

Comment: OK, I got it, I am able to set the output format, but the input format is independent and set by the program interpretation.